# Printing to a html rows and columns are backwards (JSON CALL)

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary, html-table

I have the following code in index.html which grabs a dictionary list and prints out keys and values into a table

```
$(function() {
  $('a#search').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/_search', {
      a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
      var tableData = '<table>'
      $.each(data.result, function(key, value){
        tableData += '<tr><td>' + '   ' + key + '   ' + '</td>';
        alert(key)
        $.each(value, function(val){
            alert(value[val])
            tableData += '<td>' + value[val] + '</td>';
          });
        tableData += '</tr>';
      });
      tableData += '</table>';
      $('#table').html(tableData);
    });
```

What it is grabbing is a dictionary list from search.py

```
result = defaultdict(list)
return jsonify(result=result)
```

result contains the following

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Developer': ['Office Koukan', 'Jorudan', 'Beam Software'], 'Publisher': ['Shouei', 'VAP', 'Hi Tech Expressions'], 'ReleaseDate': ['March 18, 1994', 'November 18, 1994', 'October 1, 1993'], 'Title': ['Idea no Hi', 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou', 'hunThe Hunt for Red October']})
```

However my output is as follows

```
Developer Publisher ReleaseDate Title
Office    Koukan    Jorudan Beam Software
Shouei    VAP       Hi Tech Expressions
March 18, 1994  November 18, 1994   October 1, 1993
Idea no Hi  Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou  hunThe Hunt for Red October
```

When the output should be

```
Developer      Publisher ReleaseDate Title
Office         Shouei    ...         ...
Koukan         VAP       ...         ...
Jorudan        ...       ...         ...
Beam Software  ...       ...         ...
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it SHOULD be that way when the result obviously shows in the order it IS in your example?

Comment: NOTE: `$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {` IS  the proper sequence of the parameters.  I would change your names to reflect that and perhaps clear it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of what I was referencing (note I took out the part that gets data and hard coded that, pushed the result to a div.

Note that a simple array processes differently than the array of objects using `$.each()` regarding the index vs they key object name (like the header values you have)

// sample data to use (instead of json call)

```
var mything = {
  'Developer': ['Office Koukan', 'Jorudan', 'Beam Software'],
  'Publisher': ['Shouei', 'VAP', 'Hi Tech Expressions'],
  'ReleaseDate': ['March 18, 1994', 'November 18, 1994', 'October 1, 1993'],
  'Title': ['Idea no Hi', 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou', 'hunThe Hunt for Red October']
};

$(function() {
  var data = mything;// sample data
  // create a table to append rows to
  var tableData = $('<table>');
  // append a header row
  tableData.append('<tr/>');
  // reference that header row to append header td to
  var header = tableData.find('tr').eq(0);
  $.each(data, function(headthing, value) {
    header.append('<td>' + headthing + '</td>');
    $.each(value, function(idx, myval) {
      if (!tableData.find('tr').eq(idx + 1).length) {
        tableData.append('<tr/>'); // new row if not one
      }
      // put the columns in the row for each data
      tableData.find('tr').eq(idx + 1).append('<td>' + myval + '</td>');
    });
  });
  // put the table somewhere
  $('#results').html(tableData);
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing it https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/ro5egfu3/1/

Comment: Sorry tried following your method still did not work

Comment: Did you view the  fiddle?  is that the desired output?

Comment: It is but I can traslate it to what I want I cant use find or append

Comment: Here is a link to another question with more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241437/rows-and-columns-html-table-json-response