# Rows and Columns HTML TABLE (JSON RESPONSE)

Tags: python, html, dictionary, html-table

I have the following code in index.html which grabs a dictionary list and prints out keys and values into a table

```
$(function() {
  $('a#search').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/_search', {
      a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
      var tableData = '<table>'
      $.each(data.result, function(key, value){
        tableData += '<tr><td>' + '   ' + key + '   ' + '</td>';
        alert(key)
        $.each(value, function(val){
            alert(value[val])
            tableData += '<td>' + value[val] + '</td>';
          });
        tableData += '</tr>';
      });
      tableData += '</table>';
      $('#table').html(tableData);
    });
```

What it is grabbing is a dictionary list from search.py

```
result = defaultdict(list)
return jsonify(result=result)
```

result contains the following

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Developer': ['Office Koukan', 'Jorudan', 'Beam Software'], 'Publisher': ['Shouei', 'VAP', 'Hi Tech Expressions'], 'ReleaseDate': ['March 18, 1994', 'November 18, 1994', 'October 1, 1993'], 'Title': ['Idea no Hi', 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou', 'hunThe Hunt for Red October']})
```

However my output is as follows

```
Developer Publisher ReleaseDate Title
Office    Koukan    Jorudan Beam Software
Shouei    VAP       Hi Tech Expressions
March 18, 1994  November 18, 1994   October 1, 1993
Idea no Hi  Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou  hunThe Hunt for Red October
```

When the output should be

```
Developer      Publisher ReleaseDate Title
Office         Shouei    ...         ...
Koukan         VAP       ...         ...
Jorudan        ...       ...         ...
Beam Software  ...       ...         ...
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way the JSON is formatted you need to use multiple loops. If you have control over this formatting it would be much simpler to loop though it if formatted as follows :-

```
{
  "objects" : [
  {
    "Developer": "Office Koukan",
    "Publisher": "Shouei",
    "ReleaseDate": "March 18, 1994",
    "Title": "Idea no Hi"
  },
  {
    "Developer": "Jorudan",
    "Publisher": "VAP",
    "ReleaseDate": "November 18, 1994",
    "Title": "Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou"
  },
  {
    "Developer": "Beam Software",
    "Publisher": "Hi Tech Expressions",
    "ReleaseDate": "October 1, 1993",
    "Title": "hunThe Hunt for Red October"
  }
]
}
```

This will provide you a much more natural loop as you can loop through each object instead of looping back over each field grouping multiple times.

If you can't change the format, look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/3538/.

I created a JS array to match your data. Ive looped through once to get the table header row setup. Then there's a triple nested loop to create a row for each record, then pull out the correct data for that row/column.

Hope it helps in some way

Comment: Updated fiddle to use JSON and convert to Array so it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update but i still get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` at `tableData += '<td>'+data[j][i]+'</td>'; `

Comment: The thing is that I have to change your data parts to data.result to grab the actual data

Comment: I really appreciate all your help so far

Comment: I made a print of the cols and rows and those come out right

Comment: Glad I could help :-)